# How I can get this number's format in PHP?

Tags: php

The normal number is 10000. I want it to be 1,000. How I can do it?

Comment: those are two different numbers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
echo number_format(10000);
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/number_format

Answer (score 5):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$strNum = number_format(1000);
```

There is no requirement to use the 4 parameter overload, as (from the documentation)

> If only one parameter is given, number  will be formatted without decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

So

```
number_format(1000);
```

is in effect

```
number_format(1000, 0, '.', ',');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
number_format(10000/10)
```

=)

Answer (score 1):

[number_format](http://php.net/number_format)